# Leverage Browser Caching is not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, browser-cache

The browser caching is not working as my Apache mod_expires is enabled. I have checked this through phpinfo() under Loaded Modules

Below is my code in htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 2592000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 2592000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 2592000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 2592000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 2592000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 604800 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 600 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/xhtml+xml "access plus 600 seconds"
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <FilesMatch "\\.(ico|jpe?g|png|gif|swf)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2692000, public"
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch "\\.(css)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2692000, public"
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch "\\.(js)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2692000, private"
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch "\\.(x?html?|php)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=600, private, must-revalidate"
    </FilesMatch>
    Header unset ETag
    Header unset Last-Modified
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.(bmp|css|flv|gif|ico|jpg|jpeg|JPG|js|pdf|png|svg|swf|tif|tiff)$">
        Header set Last-Modified "Mon, 27 Aug 2012 00:00:00 GMT"
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Don't expect that Stack Overflow users will enable those modules in their local server and run a battery of tests against your code just to find out how it fails to meed your needs. Perhaps you should [edit the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/19949394/edit) and explain how it fails to meet your expectations. You get an error message? The `<FilesMatch>` do not match? The HTTP headers are not being sent? The browser ignores the HTTP headers?

Comment: I am not getting any error. if it is then it will be mentioned. But no error.
I am just expecting answer or a guidance and nothing else.

Please suggest !

Comment: I have to work as per Google page speed insights

Comment: @Álvaro G. Vicario: - Its working now.,..The same code...dont know why...may be due to soem server configuration..because at that time it was not showing..but now its showing on https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/ that Leverage browser caching is working and no further modification needs..Thanks for your valuable Comments !

Answer (score 0):

check if this code works

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
<filesmatch "\.(ico|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf|woff)$">
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2678400, public"
</filesmatch>
<filesmatch "\.(html|htm)$">
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=7200, private, must-revalidate"
</filesmatch>
<filesmatch "\.(pdf)$">
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=86400, public"
</filesmatch>
<filesmatch "\.(js|css)$">
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, private"
</filesmatch>
```